# Column "username" is not defined || Discord.js and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, discord.js

I just setup a PostgreSQL database with my new Discord.js bot. I keep getting an error saying "error: column "The User's Username" does not exist". I even set it so that if there is not row, then add one and make one.

Here is the code:

```
 module.exports = (bot, message, args, con) => {
  const selecttext = `SELECT * FROM hbucks WHERE id = ${message.author.id} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`;
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM hbucks WHERE id = ${message.author.id} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`, (err, res) => { //Where id defines what row to use, this is stating that you are going to organize it by the id




    if(err) throw(err.stack);
    let sql;
    let username = message.author.username
    let authorid = message.author.id
    const inserttext = `INSERT INTO users(id, username, guildid, hbucks) VALUES(${message.author.id}, ${message.author.username}, ${message.guild.id}, ${generateXp()})`;
const insertvalues = ['${message.author.id}', '${message.author.username', '${message.guild.id}', '${generateXp()}'];

    if(!res) {
      console.log("Works!!!");
      con.query(`INSERT INTO users(id, username, guildid, hbucks) VALUES(${message.author.id}, "${message.author.username}", ${message.guild.id}, ${generateXp()}`);
    } else {

      let hBucks = res.hbucks;
      hBucks = parseInt(hBucks);
      const updatehbucks = `UPDATE hbucks SET hbucks = ${hBucks + generateXp()} WHERE id = ${authorid} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`;
const updateusername = `UPDATE hbucks SET username = "${message.author.username}" WHERE id = ${authorid} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`;

      con.query(`UPDATE hbucks SET hbucks = ${hBucks + generateXp()} WHERE id = ${authorid} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);
      con.query(`UPDATE hbucks SET username = "${message.author.username}" WHERE id = ${authorid} AND guildid = ${message.guild.id}`);

    }

  }

)}
```

Comment: (1) You have SQL injection problems all over the place, please use placeholders instead of string interpolation. (2) In standard SQL (and PostgreSQL), double quotes are for identifiers (such as table and column names), single quotes are for strings. But really, use placeholders and you'll solve this problem and prevent other problems. Also, you're trying to use string interpolation with plain old single quoted JavaScript strings in your `insertvalues` array, you need to use template strings (i.e. backticks) for interpolation to work.

Comment: @muistooshort What do you mean by placeholders? Can you give me an example if you don't mind please?

Comment: I don't know my way around the node.js PostgreSQL interfaces but there should be a way to say something like `q = con.prepare('insert into t (c1, c2) values($1, $2)')` or `q = con.prepare('insert into t (c1, c2) values (?, ?)')` and then `q.execute(6, "R'lyeh")`. Check the documentation or google it, should be able to find something now that you know what to look for.

Comment: @muistooshort Ok cool. Thank you. Do you think that will help out the undefined columns? I needed prepared statements anyways so thank you for that.

Comment: Yes, placeholders should fix both problems. The `'` in `The User's Username` is confusing your quoting as are the `"` in `username = "${message.author.username}"`.

Comment: @muistooshort Ok cool thank you. Can you find somewhere where I can read up about PostgreSQL and Prepared Statements? None of it makes any sense to me.

Comment: @muistooshort Also, I tried to do this, but it says that $1 is not defined. ` sql = con.query(`INSERT INTO hbucks(id, username, guildid, hbucks) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4)`);
      `con.query(sql, message.author.id, message.author.username, message.guild.id, generateXp())`

Comment: @VincentLauro You'll want to look into the documentation for whichever PostgreSQL client you're using to understand the format it expects for parameterized queries. Assuming you use the most-used PostgreSQL client for Node.js, `node-postgres`, you can find the appropriate documentation here: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query